# How to show final result in a h2 tag with javascript

Tags: javascript

I need a little help in JavaScript math.  I want to show the final result inside an h2 tag but I don't know how to do that (I am new to JavaScript). Please help and thanks in advance .

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Do Math</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type = "number" id = "my_input1"/>
    <input type = "number" id = "my_input2"/>
    <input type = "button" value = "Add them Together" onclick = "doMath();"/>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function doMath() {
            var my_input1 = document.getElementById('my_input1').value;
            var my_input2 = document.getElementById('my_input2').value;
            //Add them Together and Display

            var sum = parseFloat(my_input1) + parseFloat(my_input2);
            document.write("<h2>The sum is </h2>", sum);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use `document.write` after the page was loaded.

Comment: Is this what you want http://jsbin.com/oQOMEWE/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Do Math</title> 
    </head>
    <body>
      <input type = "number" id = "my_input1"/>
      <input type = "number" id = "my_input2"/>
      <input type = "button" value = "Add them Together" onclick = "doMath();"/>
      <h2 id="output"></h2>
      <script type = "text/javascript">
              function doMath() {
                  var my_input1 = document.getElementById('my_input1').value;
                  var my_input2 = document.getElementById('my_input2').value;
                  //Add them Together and Display

                  var sum = parseFloat(my_input1) + parseFloat(my_input2);
                  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "The sum is " +  sum;
               }
       </script>
    </body>
   </html>
```

See [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/JD8Agb8qeB9V9At9ceTm?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

just take an h2 tag and place the data inside it by using

```
html tag:
<h2 id='ele'></h2>


javascript:
document.getElementById('ele').innerHTML="the sum is "+sum;
```

Comment: `getElementByTagName` should be `Elements` and it returns an array(`NodeList `)

Comment: u can also use `getelementById('one')` for a specified h2 element by giving that element an id like `<h2 id='one'>`

Comment: if you like it then make it right by clicking the right signal please